# JavaFX: Empty window is displayed on first attempt

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

Preface: Newbie into Javafxml
My application is working perfectly. I just have one issue that I know should have a very simple solution, but I can't come up with anything more.

When i run my application, i get an empty window. 
[Empty Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7aEC.png)

I have to resize the window in order to get the required

[Resized Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHnCY.png)

```
@FXML
void invoice(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/Invoice2.fxml"));
    Parent planner;
    try {
        planner = (Parent) loader.load();
        stage.setTitle("Order Details");
        stage.getScene().setRoot(planner);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

FXML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<TitledPane collapsible="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"        minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1200.0" text="Invoice" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.InvoiceController">
  <content>
     <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <children>
          <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.08355795148247978" layoutX="166.0" layoutY="108.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
          <items>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" styleClass="body-default" stylesheets="@main.css" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
                 <children>
                    <Button fx:id="back" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#BackButton" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="79.0" styleClass="btn-default" stylesheets="@main.css" text="Back" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                 <children>
                    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.7078260869565217" layoutX="158.0" layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="283.0" prefWidth="577.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                      <items>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                             <children>
                                <TableView fx:id="invoicelisttb1" layoutX="71.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="281.0" prefWidth="404.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                  <columns>
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="order" prefWidth="148.0" text="Order No." />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="167.0" text="Name" />
                                      <TableColumn fx:id="price" prefWidth="173.0" text="Price" />
                                  </columns>
                                </TableView>
                             </children>
                          </AnchorPane>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
                             <children>
                                <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="91.0" styleClass="bold" stylesheets="@main.css" text="Order No:" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="233.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="txtorder" editable="false" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="83.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="58.0" />
                                <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="91.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="77.0" styleClass="bold" stylesheets="@main.css" text="Price:" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="246.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="txtprice" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="91.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="83.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="58.0" />
                                <Button fx:id="btnprice" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#enterPrice" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="113.0" styleClass="btn-default" stylesheets="@main.css" text="Enter Price" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="58.0" />
                             </children>
                          </AnchorPane>
                      </items>
                    </SplitPane>
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
          </items>
        </SplitPane>
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  </content>
  </TitledPane>
```

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: Is your main class also located inside the `view` folder?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted: the cause of this is likely to be elsewhere in your code. This is going to be impossible for anyone to help with unless you include a [MCVE].

Comment: No, it's located in a different package @Maslor

Comment: See my edited version, i have included the fxml file too this time @James_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working on it for days, I finally solved it by simply putting the entire fxml's structure in another Anchor Pane. I don't know why that solved it or how that solved it, but when I wrapped the entire GUI in Anchor Pane, it started working fine.

Comment: simple as it sounds, i had the same problem and this solved it for me. have an upvote, dear.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
try {
   Parent planner = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Invoice2.fxml"));

   stage.setTitle("Order Details");
   stage.setScene(new Scene(planner));
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead of `stage.getScene().setRoot(planner)` I have used `stage.setScene(new Scene(planner));`.

Comment: Thankyou for such a quick response. I have already tried this one. This code works perfectly fine for all other windows, it's just this particular window where there is problem

Comment: What is your initial size of your window? Do you have a `Pref Width` and a `Pref Height`? Check also your fxml file within your IDE (not within the Scene Builder). Sometimes there might be errors.

Comment: Yes i have set these two attributes. When i open it with my IDE, it works fine. It's just that when I run the application, this window appears completely empty, when i resize it, it works fine.

Comment: Mmmh, a bit strange. Can you edit your question with a minimal excerpt of your program containing the accordant window?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/Invoice2.fxml"));` change the resource to `"../view/Invoice2.fxml"`. This will work if your project directory structure is something like this:

```
project
|
\_ view
|  |
|  \_ Invoice2.fxml
\_ main
   \_ Main.java
```

The `"../path"` indicates that the selected path is in the same parent directory, not inside our current directory.